# How to return a node property expressed by a variable?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

```
MATCH (p:Product {id:'123'}) return p.$color
```

Where '$color' is a parameter passed from a function which generates the cypher query.

Comment: Can APOC do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the value of a property named "foo" from a `p` node by using the `p["foo"]` syntax.

So, if you have a `$color` parameter that has the name of a `Product` property, this would work:

```
MATCH (p:Product {id:'123'})
RETURN p[$color];
```